# How to get browser cookies size via javasctiprt method

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to calculate my domain cookies size via pure javascript method. I know the cookies size limit for a domain in all browsers but I need to know is domain and subdomain cookies are sharing the total size of the domain?

For example, **test.com** and **aap.test.com** are having when I calculate the total size of the cookies for a domain is considering both domains?
Please help me to know about this issue.

Comment: How are you setting your cookies? Note that `httponly` cookies will not be visible at all through Javascript

Comment: @Kaddath Thank you for your response. I am setting cookies in javascript like 
document.cookie = 'name=value;expire=;path=/'